# Avoid interpolating over constraints

Tags: python, numpy, csv, scipy, matplotlib-basemap

Hi I am in the process of interpolating data, but the data from N. America, for example, affect the data from Europe (see figure). I have found out that I must add constraints to the data so that the individual regions, e.g. Europe or N. America, do not interact with each other. I wanted to ask how to get to these constraints of the individual regions worldwide.

The data I use are stored in a CSV file.

Result:[image]

Comment: This looks like a complex operation and I am not aware of anything in Numpy or Scipy that can do such a thing directly. This is the kind of operation for GIS (eg. QGIS, ArcGIS, etc). GDAL may help for programming or GIS libraries in general. That being said, note that seeking for libraries, tools or recommendation is off-topic on Stack-Overflow. If you want to do the operation manually, then be aware that this looks like a tough problem and It is certainly better to search for an algorithm before trying to implement that using some specific Python libraries.

Comment: Is it possible to split the CSV (e.g. a CSV file that only has data from Europe)? Can you then interpolate the individual files and plot them on a map? 
Is this a realistic approach? I'm just not sure how I can fit all the interpolated data onto one map.

Comment: AFAIK, GIS can do the splitting and the plotting easily. I am not sure for the interpolation but AFAIK they generally provide many interpolation methods. If you want to specifically  split the left and right parts, then this can be done with Numpy relatively easily. What you exactly want to achieve is not clear to me tough.

Comment: I want to build an isoscape that simulates isotope data in precipitation worldwide. Unfortunately, I have little experience in programming, so I'm really helpless at times.

Comment: I am also really not sure whether I will get right results from my approach.

Comment: I am not familiar with this domain. I think there is a huge gap between what you want to do and how to implement it and Stack Overflow only help if you have a (much more) *precise programming* question. If this is not the case, then you can possibly ask question on other stack exchange websites like https://gis.stackexchange.com for example.